# Java - How to build a library to record runtime data?

Tags: design, java, design-patterns

I'm working on building a library in Java which could provide the ability to record runtime data.

For instance consider the below code:

```
public interface ItemElement {
    public int accept(ShoppingVisitor visitor);
}

public class Book implements ItemElement {

    private int price;
    private String title;
    
    public Book(int cost, String title){
        this.price=cost;
        this.title=title;
    }
    
    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    @Override
    public int accept(ShoppingVisitor visitor) {
        return visitor.visit(this);
    }
}

public interface ShoppingVisitor {
    int visit(Book book);
}

public class ShoppingVisitorImpl implements ShoppingVisitor {

    @Override
    public int visit(Book book) {
        // business logic
    }
}
```

For MRE, consider that I want to build a library which could record the price and title of Book objects when ShoppingVisitor visits the object.

To achieve the same, I am planning to create a library which would have the below:
a) A method annotation which could be used to define which methods to intercept.
b) Define Aspects in the library (AOP) to intercept the method's execution which are using the annotation and record the before/after state of the arguments.

For instance,
The Library would have below:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface RecordArgs {
}

@Aspect
public class RecordMethodArgsAspect {

    @Before("@annotation(RecordArgs)")
    public Object logMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
         //record method arguments i.e. Book object in above example
    }
}
```

Using the annotation in client code would look something like:

```
@RecordArgs
public int visit(Book book) {
    // business logic
}
```

**Question**: How can I provide a generic way such that the domain classes like Book in above example, have the ability to define what fields should be recorded and the Aspects in library can identify and record the same and its extensible in a way that when the structure of Book class changes in future then there shouldn't be a need to change recording code in the library?

Comment: **Annotations** seem appropriate, especially as they are already used by JPA entities (persistence). And you might like **lombok** too for its boiler plating. But be sure of not overdoing the architecture.